# Why isn't the OnSessionEnding event triggering on program exit?

Tags: wpf, f#

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "PresentationCore.dll"
#r "PresentationFramework.dll"
#r "System.Xaml.dll"
#r "WindowsBase.dll"
#endif

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Input
open System.Windows.Controls

type InheritTheApp() =
    inherit Application()

    override t.OnStartup(args) =
        base.OnStartup(args)

        let win = Window()
        win.Title <- "Inherit The App"
        win.Show()

    override t.OnSessionEnding(args) =
        base.OnSessionEnding(args)

        let res = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your data?",t.MainWindow.Title,MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxImage.Question,MessageBoxResult.Yes)

        args.Cancel <- (res = MessageBoxResult.Yes)

[<STAThreadAttribute>]
do
    let app = new InheritTheApp()
    app.Run() |> ignore
```

This is the third example from the `Application = Code + Markup` book by Charles Petzold translated to F# from C# except it is not working for some reason. On exit, the program should pop up a message box asking me whether I want to save data and abort if the Cancel button is pressed.

I do not know why, but the program just exits without showing the message box if I `Alt+F4` or click the `X`on the top right of the Window.

Comment: Why not use [FsXAML](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml) + [FsVM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.ViewModule.Core/) or even [Gjallarhorn](http://reedcopsey.github.io/Gjallarhorn/)?

Comment: If you have just started to use WPF, then I guess you have a lot of questions. I would advise you to join the [SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I looked into FsXAML, but it has no documentation anywhere, so I can't use it. In fact most of the UI stuff in F# that I found on the net is quite advanced from my perspective and presupposes some experience from the user. I never heard about FsVM or Gjallarhorn. I'll look into them.

Comment: Very useful and convenient things. You can always ask about him in chat or in the channel of slack (he is more active)

Comment: And, quite honestly, I'm not sure that the Petzold book is good to start learning WPF.

Comment: I'm sorry, for what my comments are off topic.

Comment: @FoggyFinder I saw the book in one of the slides in a Phil Trelfold interview, so I got it. I looked into FsVM just now and it too does not seem to have any documentation. Also Gjalarhorn seems to be in the vein of some of the other UI projects in the sense that it is made to solve some of the problems of standard WPF programming. Which is fine, but I am not sure I care about this right now - I just want to figure out how to do standard UI programming.

Comment: Is there some other resource you would suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116399/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-marko-grdinic).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the event is not triggering is because `SessionEnding` only triggers on OS log out or shutdown, not on program exit. I should have read more closely.